# Share css and ts across projects

Tags: css, angular, typescript, share

There is a need to share some CSS and TS across multiple Angular projects. Is there a way to do it? Copy-pasting isn't looking so good for that purpose.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Answer (score 2):

For each project you can try to add this in your angular.json. In the Styles part where normally there is other styles from your node package.

```
"styles": [

              "path/to/style/style.scss", // Your  custom style
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" //exemple of package style

            ]
```

EDIT : 
If you need to  load an external css.
you can use as mentioned in your comment of your first post use "link" in the index.html from your src app folder. For each ng project. Hope it will correspond to your request.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="server/with/css/custom.css">
```

Comment: But I need to share them. Meaning they need to be accessible from different computers since it's a team developed applications. Applications are shared via gitlab

Comment: Okay, well if you have an external css to load, you can use as mentioned in your comment of your first post use "link" in the index.html from your src app folder. For each ng project.
Hope it will correspond to your request.
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://server/with/css/custom.css">